# How can I show the tooltip on disable GridViewItem

Tags: uwp

I have some disable GridViewItem and enable GridViewItem in the GridView.
I want show the tooltip on the disabled GridViewItem when the mouse pointer on it.
But I can not show the tooltip on disable GridViewItem.

I have found some solution for WPF.(Use the ShowOnDisabled property)
But there is no ShowOnDisabled in UWP.

My code snippet.

Xaml:

```
<root:ScanedAppDataTemplateSelector x:Name="ScanedAppDataTemplateSelector"
                                            Eenable="{StaticResource ScanedAppItemTemplatEenable}"
                                            Disable="{StaticResource ScanedAppItemTemplateDisable}"/>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ScanedAppItemTemplateDisable" x:DataType="root:AppInfo">
    <Grid Width="70" Height="95">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock Text="Disabled Item"/>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <Image x:Name="ScanedAppItemtBtn" Source="{x:Bind BitmapIcon, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ScanedAppItemName" Text="{x:Bind AppName, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<GridView Name="ScanedAppGridView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind _dataContext.ScanedAppModelItem }"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ScanedAppDataTemplateSelector}"
              SelectionMode="Multiple"
              IsItemClickEnabled="False"/>
```

I use DataTemplateSelector to disable the GridViewItem.

DataTemplateSelector :

```
protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var viewModel = item as AppInfo;
        var selectorItem = container as SelectorItem;

        if (selectorItem != null && viewModel != null)
        {
            if (viewModel.IsDisable)
            {
                selectorItem.IsEnabled = false;
                return disable;
            }
        }

        return enable;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code snippet you mentioned.

Comment: Hi MatthiasSommer, I had update the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I show the tooltip on disable GridViewItem

Currently, UWP `Tooltip` does not provide such api to display the tip on the disable element. If you do want this feature, please feel free to ask for this feature on [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).

Comment: is the Tooltip feature available on disable element yet? The above link for UserVoice is borken so asking for info.

Comment: I'm not in msft any more, you may get more info from QA